# Tikz package to draw series-parallel graphs with many vars in series/parallel?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

*Goal versus the result: notice that the variables 2 and 3 on the right are inferior to 1 while the purpose was to have the variables 1, 2 and 3 equal like on the left.*

[image]

The [code](http://www.texample.net/media/tikz/examples/TEX/series-and-parallel-graph-diagrams.tex) from [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/series-and-parallel-graph-diagrams/) and its remix below as MWE.

**How can you draw series-parallel graphs in Tikz for LaTex where a connection can have many vars such as 1 var, 2 var and N number of vars with equal layering like on the left?**

*MWE*

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\serblock
{\parblock{\block{1}}{\parblock{\block{2}}{\block{3}}}}
{\parblock{\block{4}}{\parblock{\block{5}}{\block{6}}}}
\end{figure}
```